# Displaying subset of Backbone.js collection depending on Screen Size

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm using Marionette on top of Backbone.js, and am wanting to display a subset of a collection, with the number of Items showing dependant on the browser width.

> Example: 20 items in collection. Each ItemView shows in a 100px wide div.
>
> If the browser width is <= 600px, only display 5, etc.

I would have buttons on either side to change the view-denoted index for where in the array to start showing.

I can get the subset of the array, using a loop through the starting index -> number of displayed and Collection.at(i).

```
//var collection already exists 
var subset = new Collection();
var N = floor( screenwidth / 100 ); 
for(var i = index; i< index+N; i++){
    subset.add(collection.at(i));
}
```

How would I pass the screenwidth into the render function, and how would I re-render on screensize changes? Would a jquery bind on the resize event help somehow?

(Note: number to show logic is not exactly correct, since I do not yet know how many is best compared to the other onscreen elements)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use another approach:

1. Add boolean attribute representing current item's visibility to your
   Collection's Model.
2. Depending on that attribute change visibility (by CSS `display`
   property) of DOM element in appropriate View's `render` method.

So the code might look like this:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        ...
        display: true
    },
    ...
});

var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MyModel,
    ...
});

var MyItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    model: MyModel,
    ...
    render: function() {
        if (this.model.get('display'))
            this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) ).show();
        else
            this.$el.hide();
    },
    ...
});

var MyCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    collection: MyCollection,
    ...
    initialize: function() {
        $(window).resize(_.bind(this.resize, this));
    },
    resize: function() {
        ...
        var N = floor(screenwidth / 100); 
        this.collection.each(function(model, i) {
            model.set('display', i < N);
        });
    },
    ...
});
```

Comment: After some further research, another possibility might be to implement the "filter" function, as specified in the Marionette documentation, 

["CollectionView:Filter"](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.1/marionette.collectionview.html#collectionviews-filter)

`filter: function (child, index, collection) { return index > displayIndex && index < (screenwidth determined number) }` ..... Thoughts?

Comment: I implemented this logic, and it works well. However, two important things are necessary: calling resize after binding it in the initialize pass (MyCollectionView), and setting `modelEvents:{ "change":"render"}`, otherwise it doesn't initialize to the screensize on the first pass, and the models didn't auto-render themselves. Note I'm using Marionette 2.4.1, vs your bare Backbone implementation. I will wait for another approach before marking as answered, but this does indeed work. Thanks!

Comment: One downside to this approach is that it requires rendering all items to the DOM, which can be prohibitive if the elements in the collection is large. (pagination, etc)